# Get taxonomy terms for all the wordpress posts in an archive

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I am using the following function to display the selected taxonomy terms in a archive page.

```
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'dt_portfolio_category', '<ul class="styles"><li>', ',</li><li>', '</li></ul>' );
```

The above function only displays taxonomy terms of the first posts not all of them.

Is there any way of doing it ?
Also the terms should not repeat, they should come only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the code inside the loop.
Hope that will do.

Sample CODE :

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'dt_portfolio_category', '<ul class="styles"><li>', ',</li><li>', '</li></ul>' );
endwhile;
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example

Comment: That is perfect Tristup. How do I avoid the duplicates now ?

Comment: Any ways I fixed that. Thanks